# Outlook 2013 on Windows 10 - signature dialog does not appear

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I cannot get the dialog which usually displays email signature options to appear on my Outlook 2013 installation.  For example, if I go to the menu option File->Options->Mail then click Signatures... no dialog is displayed.

I've already tried the registry hacks described in articles such as http://www.thewindowsclub.com/unable-to-add-signature-in-outlook but that didn't fix my problem.

I also tried running an Office Repair, but no changes there either.

Can anyone suggest how to get the signature problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was finally able to get it to work by doing a full re-installed.  No other changes.  After that signatures & all other features appear to be working OK.